# Gradle task doesn't execute in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, build.gradle

I've tried to get a gradle task to execute for a lib module 'lib1' in an Android Studio project. It should run with command 'gradlew assembleDebug' or 'gradlew assemble' but it never runs.

```
task copy(type: Copy, dependsOn: ':lib1:assembleDebug') << {
  println "copying"
}
```

I tried a simpler task with no dependency and it never seems to run either.

```
task hello << {
  println 'hello world'
}
```

This runs but it's only in the configuration phase.

```
task hello {
  println 'hello world'
}
```

I need to get a copy to work in the execution phase after the library module assembled. Any clues what to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add your task to the task dependency graph somehow. Typically, by making an existing task depend on it. In this case, `copy` depends on `assembleDebug`, which simply means, if you run the `copy` task, `assembleDebug` must run first. This **does not** mean that running `assembleDebug` will cause `copy` to run. Add this to your build.

```
assemble.dependsOn copy
```

Now running `gradlew assemble` will cause the `copy` task to execute.

Your second task is correctly defined but again, no other task depends on it so it will only execute if you run it explicitly via `gradlew hello` or by adding a dependency as mentioned above.

Your third task prints a line during the configuration phase because that closure is evaluated only during that phase. It is the `<<` operator that adds a `doLast` action which is run at execution time.

Comment: Is there a way to make the copy task always execute after assemble is finished? I simply am trying to copy the library to another location after a debug or release build.

Comment: You could do `assemble.finalizedBy copy` to ensure it is always run *after* the assemble task.